# Switch on USB extension

Tags: power, usb, toggle-switch

I plan on adding a rocker switch to only the positive wire in a usb extension cord with a 3d printed shell for the connection. Will the circuit be safe with the switch connecting the positive wire be turned off (not connected) while the negative wire stay? Meaning when device is off, positive wire is not connected while all others including negative stay connected. This will be a usb light plugged into a wall adapter and into a wall outlet.

Answer (score 0):

That will be fine. Your circuit is just like using a battery for the light and cutting one wire is all you need.

If you were using the USB data lines then it would not be a good idea to leave those connected while the power was switched off as it could result in damage to the unpowered device data inputs.

[image]

*Figure 1. A random image from [here](https://composant-electronique.fr/connecteur-usb-conn-usb-a-w#_).*

If you have a look at the USB-A connector you will notice that the outer pins (+5 V and GND) are longer to ensure that they connect first to power up the device before the data lines connect.